# UML( Domain Class Diagram) is my Domain Class Diagram correct?

Tags: uml, diagram, software-design, class-diagram

Currently I am dealing with UMl diagrams of the SOS game that I am planning to create, But I am not sure if my domain class diagram is correct. Can please someone tell me that if I have aany problem with my domain class diagram?
Thanks.

[interface sketch 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp4ug.png)

[interface sketch 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBYV1.jpg)

[interface sketch 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvIMy.png)

[image]

Comment: Nobody can tell without knowing the domain, except by guessing. So you want us to guess?

Comment: First thanks for your reply.It is simple SOS game played with 2 player either computer or human player.I have all other diagrams like use case, partial use case ,activity , use case templates. Which one I need to post here to inform you sir?

Comment: You should go with @GholamaliIrani's answer. It's probably the best you can get. Describing the domain in detail would just blow this question. Next time try to get down to a certain issue that can be asked. E.g. the generalization of the `Player`.

Comment: @Airhead this question is a poor fit over there for the same reasons as it is here. Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with. See also: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: Thank you for your replies helped me a alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @ThomasKilian said in the comments, It is hard to correct this model without proper domain documents.

I offer some hints just by my knowledge from your pictures,
You have some mistakes and some bad designs:

1. **Human Player 1** and **Human Player 2** are not Classes. They are instances of one class can be named : **Human Class** that be inherited from Player.
2. **Score** can be an attribute of **Player**, not a class. If it should be class, a relationship needs between Score and Player.
3. Your Menu class can be decompose to it's sub classes.
4. 7*7 Grid class can be changed to Grid class with the rows and columns attribute.
5. After Frame class, you can use a class named **Cell**, then **Filled with S** Class, **Filled with O** and **Empty** Class can be Inherited from Cell (Not Frame)
6. In professional view, You SOS Game class is a **GOD Class**. (See this book: Object Oriented Design Heuristics, Arthur J. Riel, 1996, to handle it)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I changed my diagram according to your answer.